# Angular/ajax app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am new to angular js with some knowledge of javascript and jquery and ajax i am making one app that will have multiple user on it and when user click item form user list it will redirect to that particular user page without refreshing page..

Suppose we have multiple user like

user A, user B,user C and so on and when user A is selected it will open page of user A..

How can we do it by using angular Routes and all and fetch json from angular $http and parse in html...

Plz help

```
{
    "datas": {
        "show_dashboard_access_page": false,
        "login_status": "signedin",
        "new_io": true,
        "bst_users": [{
            "userA": {
                "user_logo": "image path",
                "partner_since": "Jan 2013",
                "status_now": "bronze",
                "year_calculated": 2016,
                "total": 300000,
                "year_wise_usage": 123000,
                "storage_wise_usage": 73000,
                "server_wise_usage": 50000,
                "order": 1
            },
            "userB": {
                "user_logo": "image path",
                "partner_since": "Feb 2014",
                "status_now": "silver",
                "year_calculated": 2016,
                "total": 300000,
                "year_wise_usage": 160000,
                "storage_wise_usage": 60000,
                "server_wise_usage": 100000,
                "order": 2
            },
            "userC": {
                "user_logo": "image path",
                "partner_since": "Mar 2014",
                "status_now": "silver",
                "year_calculated": 2016,
                "total": 300000,
                "year_wise_usage": 180000,
                "storage_wise_usage": 80000,
                "server_wise_usage": 100000,
                "order": 3
            }
            }]
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: That's basic routing, you can find solution in any starting tutorial and on official angularjs page, you've put no effort to find the solution

Comment: Can you suggest something i dont have any experience on angular

Comment: At Stack, we prefer not to give out code. We prefer that you try it, if it doesn't work, then you post your code, actual/expected results and any error messages and then we can help. Google angular routing

Comment: Ok i will b back soon if i get some errors